# how to use qunit and promise to test my function?

Tags: promise, qunit

I have two function: 
    test.set(object details)
    test.onChanged.addListener(function(object info) {...})
fired onChanged when a test is set.
So, how should I use qunit and promise to test it?

```
 QUnit.asyncTest("onChanged with set", function(assert) {
    new Promise(function(r1) {
        test.set({});
        r1();
    }).then(function() {
        new Promise(function(r2) {
            test.onChanged.addListener(function(info) {
                assert.ok(true, "onChanged callback");
                assert.deepEqual(info, {}, "onChanged result");
                r2();
            });
        });
    }).then(function() {
        QUnit.start();
    });
});
```

But, it does not run.

Comment: Use mocha, it's more modern and has built in promise support, otherwise use the normal asynchronous syntax

Comment: I'm confused... does `test.set()` return a Promise? Why wouldn't you simply add the `onChanged` handler then call `test.set()` and see that the handler was called?